# MySQL divide result in several variables?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I wanted to show for me the amount of orders of each buyer. And that works very well.

```
 select name, count(orderid) from buyer natural join reservation group by buyerid;
```

I get two results, one with 12 orders and the other one with 4 orders. Now I want to split this two outcomes at the quantity of their orders.
For example all people who purchased more than 10 objects should be classified with an '+'. Those who bought < 10 objects should get a '-'. The difficulty is there are only single orders in the table reservations, which means: Person A ordered a Ship (Obj1), Person A ordered a DVD (Obj2) etc...
The orders are single data sets in this table no sum or grouping (thats the reason for the select statement above).

However, I have another empty table to put the "name" and the "class" and it should be done by the using of a procedure.

Like this:

```
  create procedure dividing (in decisionpoint int)
  begin
  set @var = select count(orderid) from buyer....group by buyerid;
  -->Error because I get 2 Rows (Allowed is only one, but how can I solve this? I will continue with the logic)
  IF @var >= decisionpoint THEN do....
  ELSE do...
  end;
```

So it is actually simple but I don't see the solution at the moment... Maybe you are able to manage this.

Comment: select your count from an outer query with a CASE WHEN countOrders >10 THEN ..ELSE...

Comment: Hmm... We have two persons A (20 orders) and B (10 orders). B gets a - and A gets a +. But how can i check this with if or case conditions. Make an example. Try to write your outer query. Because you will get of course 1 data sat but then i can not differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can turn your query into an inner query and do another outer SELECT to check for your condition

```
SELECT name,orders,
       CASE WHEN orders > 10 THEN "+"
            ELSE "-"
            END AS status
FROM
  (select name, count(orderid) as orders
    from buyer 
    natural join reservation 
    group by buyerid
  )AS T;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfa50/4)

output:

```
name    orders  status
A       20        +
B        4        -
```

Comment: sounds good, i will try it. But I guess you can not use an IF construct instead of your case construct?

Comment: of course you can use if:

`SELECT name,orders,
       IF (orders > 10,"+","-") AS status
FROM
  (select name, count(orderid) as orders
    from buyer 
    natural join reservation 
    group by buyerid
  )AS T;`

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, you would write code like this:

```
insert into nameclass(name, class)
    select b.name,
           (case when count(r.orderid) < 10 then '-' else '+' end) 
    from buyer b join
         reservation r
         using (??)
    group by b.buyerid;
```

You really cannot use an `if` clause, because that operates on scalars but you need to operate on rows.

As a note:  don't use `natural join`.  It is a bug waiting to happen.  It joins tables based only on the names of fields -- it doesn't even use declared foreign keys.  Instead, put the keys in a `using` or `on` clause.

Comment: Thanks, worked well. However, I was wondering about the IF clause problem in this scenario. Can you explain, how does IF work only on "scalars" and not for this practice?

Comment: @EchoCache . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?